Django Logout request returning forbidden 403 CSRF related
from rest_framework import views, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login,logout
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes=[AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return Response({'message': 'Logged in successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class LogoutView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({'message': 'Logged out successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@csrf_exempt
def logoutView(request):
    print(request.COOKIES)
    logout(request)
    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Logged out successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class UserInfoView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        return Response({'username': user.username}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


When sending request to login or userinfoview it works fine with csrf tokens. however the class LogoutView returns forbidden 403. The logoutView FUNCTION works fine ONLY when csrf_exmpt is applied. when printing request.cookies its returning:
{'csrftoken': 'DdQZJC56QBSAcDqXVlrXz4mMeVWitpNV', 'sessionid': 'poul3qidl8xw4k5bp2rwazbxo76eq9sq'}
which is what it returns in all the other classes as well. i tried to csrf exmpt the class because thats what i ultimitly want to use instead of the function for the cleaner looking code but couldnt figure out how to exmpt the class. moreover, i dont want to exmpt the csrf to begin with unless its the only solution.
EDIT: after adding method_decorator(csrf_protect) to login i figured out csrf was not working for login either. cause i started getting cSRF token missing. so the error is related to CSRF token misisng.
i updated the code turning logout class to a get method and that worked. while that is A solution. it still doesnt answer it properly. how to set the csrf token to be recongnized.
Note: using react as frontend.

If you wanna use csrf_token and session, you must set session settings in the REST_FRAMEWORK settings.py

is this what your mentioning
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'LAX'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600  # 2 weeks
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
